# Calling a method for *this influences SOMEHOW other parameters, C++

Tags: c++, oop, method-call

I have two methods:

```
bigint& bigint::operator=(const bigint& b){
    init();
    for(int i = N-1; i >= N - b.getLength(); i--){
        un[i] = b.un[i];
    }
    setLength(b.getLength());
    return *this;
}

void bigint::init(){
    int L = getLength();
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++){
        un[N-L+i] = 0;
    }
    setLength(1);
}
```

First is called `operator=` in the code, which assigns value of `b` to `*this`.

Class `bigint` represents big integers of max length = N. Instance of `bigint` contains array of length equal to `N`.

What's my problem:
I can't determine why calling the method `init()`, which zeros every element of `*this`, influences also the parametr `b`. 
It seems like it zeros also the `b`.

When I delete the `init()` calling from the `operator=` method, `b` is not modified, but I need to zero the `bigint *this` before assigning it some value.

I don't understand what's really going on.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Shouldn't be possible, const is const, at least if bigint is const correct. Can you show us more code? Like the call and getLength? Also, you don't call it on itself, like `bigint a = a;`, right? Have you used a debugger so far or printed out variable configurations in between, like before and after the call of init?

Comment: Did you correctly implement the copy constructor? It seems like `un` is a pointer, so the default copy constructor will just copy the pointer, but not the underlying memory. Then it can happen that two different `bigint` objects use the same array for their data.